# Select part of an integer in SQL (GBQ)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, integer, extract

I have the following database on Google Big Query (SQL Standard) with the date and the revenue. Both in int format. I need to get the totals by month and year. I am not able to get the part of the date I am interested on. Basically the numbers of position 1 and 6 from the first column.

**Revenue Database:**

[image: Revenue Database]

This is what I have tried but then I need to run this code for every month separately:

```
SELECT sum(revenue)
from revenue.table
where date between 20210601 and 20210630
```

Any clue on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Poor design choice to store dates as integer values. Alter to date data type, and everything will become easier.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's a big query database. I cannot change the type.

Comment: Simply group by the leftmost 6 digits of the `date` column

Comment: Thanks Martin!! How can I code that? I have been two hours for this and I don't know how to select them ;(

Comment: You have still not told us which dbms you're using...

Comment: Also, most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Comment: As @jarlh has asked a couple of times, the answer to that is dependent upon your DBMS

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using Google Big Query directly with SQL standard... I've updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: I'd simply try `date/100`, and hope for integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own solution in case it helps someone in the future:

```
SELECT substring(CAST(date AS STRING), 1, 6) AS month, sum(revenue) AS total_rev
FROM `revenue.table`
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC
```

Comment: There is a lot of effort in providing your own solution to which I agree upon. It would be really nice if you provide a reason or explanation for the changes that are reflected in providing the above solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is in `int` format, then use arithmetic:

```
select floor(date / 100) as yyyymm, sum(revenue)
from revenue.table
group by yyyymm;
```

If it were stored properly as a `date`, then you would use the built-in [`date_trunc()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc):

```
select date_trunc(date, month) as yyyymm, sum(revenue)
from revenue.table
group by yyyymm;
```

There are similar functions for related data types: `timestamp_trunc()` and `datetime_trunc()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` is actually an `INTEGER`, then I would:

`GROUP BY DIV(date/100)`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with below

```
select 
  date_trunc(parse_date('%Y%m%d', '' || date), month) month,
  sum(revenue) revenue
from `revenue.table`
group by month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT substring(cast(Date as string),1,6) YearMonth,
       sum(Revenue)
FROM `<Dataset_NAME>.<Table_NAME>`
group by YearMonth;
```

Comment: how it is different from OP answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043251/5221944 ?

Comment: OP named the field as Month but I say it, "YearMonth".